# EJS - include an include from a different directory than the current

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I need to include an include using EJS templating from a different directory than the one I'm cuurently in. My folder structure is this:

```
-views
---includes
-----navigation.html
-----footer.html
---page
-----layout.html
```

When I try to do an `<% include includes/navigation.html %>` in my `page/layout.html` it returns:

> Could not find include include file.

My view engine setup is below:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.use(expressLayouts);
```

My question is this: It's to my understanding that `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` sets the path for ALL views. But I don't want to just have `views/includes` because then trying to include other includes that are NOT in `views/includes` would not work, correct?

How do I include includes in another directory than the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When settings views in your main app, just include the directory you want to use as the "includes" directory:

```
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'), path.join(__dirname, 'views/includes/')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do this in your layout.html file:

```
<%- include('../includes/navigation.html') %>
```

../ means that you are trying to access the parent directory (from your layout.html file).